# Does The Boot override Intangible?

Tags: slay-the-spire

The effect of The Boot relic states "Whenever you would deal 4 or less unblocked Attack damage, increase it to 5". The Intangible buff, which can be used by the Nemesis boss, states "Reduce ALL damage and HP loss you take to 1".

If I have The Boot relic and play an attack against a Nemesis with Intangible, how much damage will it do? Does it deal 5 damage from The Boot or 1 damage from Intangible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, The Boot overrides Intangible, so Attacks will deal 5 damage instead of 1. I confirmed this myself and uploaded a video showing it.